# It (Plural words) help or helps you?

Tags: word-usage, usage

So from my understanding, you use "helps" instead of "help" when you have a third person on present form, and the action is right after the subject of the phrase, is that correct? (one example of its usage, not generalizing)

But for a phrase that uses the "it" in the plural form, which one is correct:

> Callbacks help you to close deals...

OR

> Callbacks helps you (to?) close deals...

Comment: With the exception of "I" and "you" (which use _help_), the general pattern is _singular/uncountable noun + helps_ and _plural noun + help_.

Comment: To learn English, you must learn to conjugate English verbs. There are thousands of websites that list the full conjugation of nearly every verb, e.g. [this one.](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, we use "helps" with third person singular, "help" with all other forms.

I help. You help. He/she/it helps.

We help. You help. They help.

If you are not using a pronoun but some other noun, then you use the third person forms, "helps" for singular and "help" for plural.

So in your example, "callbacks"is a common noun, the plural of "callback". Thus the correct usage is, "Callbacks help ..."